# How to config an signing order for the api on docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm a SQL dev and somhow I have to solve this problem,

Is there any way to set and order of the sign order on the API?
In my company it's set for 3 people to sign, two 'static'(our directors) and one variable (the new business partner getting registred on our eletronic form)

I know that when doing it manualy we can set an order for the docments to be sent.
Like send the document for the new partner and  only after he finishes signing the document is sent to our director already signed.
But is it possible to do via API? If so, how?

I could find anything about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is call "routing order" in DocuSign and you can specify it at the API when you add recipients like this:

```
 "recipients": {
        "carbonCopies": [
            {
                "email": "cc@something.com",
                "name": "CC Name",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }
        ],
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "signer@something.com",
                "name": "Signer Name",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
```

Routing order is to tell DocuSign to ask recipients to sign in this order (ascending) from lower to higher. If there are two recipients with the same routing order - they both get it at the same time. If you don't specify routing order - again, they both get it in the same time.